# Erro em clausula where SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, flutter

Oi, estou com um pequeno problema no seguinte método:

```
Future<List> getAllTarefasMediaPrioridade(String status) async{
  Database dbTarefas = await db;
  List<Tarefas> listTarefasMediaPrioridade;
  List listMap2 = await dbTarefas.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tarefasTable"); 
  if(status.isEmpty){
    try{
      List listMap = await dbTarefas.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tarefasTable"
          " WHERE $prioridadeColumn = Media");
      for(Map m in listMap) listTarefasMediaPrioridade.add(Tarefas.fromMap(m));
    } catch (e){
      e.toString();
    }

    return listTarefasMediaPrioridade;
  }
  else{
    return listTarefasMediaPrioridade = List();
  }
}
```

Quando faço : `List listMap2 = await dbTarefas.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tarefasTable");`, ele me retorna todos os dados que tenho no meu bd :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ai está correto, mas quando vou inserir um where :

```
final String prioridadeColumn = "prioridadeColumn";
List listMap = await dbTarefas.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tarefasTable WHERE $prioridadeColumn = Media");
```

Recebo o erro: `no such column: Media (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tarefasTable WHERE prioridadeColumn = Media`

Não consigo identificar o que está errado.

Comment: está entendendo Media como uma coluna, acho que o correto seria `SELECT * FROM $tarefasTable WHERE $prioridadeColumn = 'Media'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está fazendo uma comparação no sql porém ela deve ser feita utilizando uma string em sql.

```
 List listMap = await dbTarefas.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tarefasTable" +
      " WHERE $prioridadeColumn = 'Media'");
```

A query tem que ficar assim:

```
SELECT * FROM $tarefasTable WHERE $prioridadeColumn = 'Media'
```

O problema é a palavra `Media` na sua aplicação que deve ser representada como uma string em sql.

Comment: Bacana, agora funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

tente mudar

```
List listMap = await dbTarefas.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tarefasTable"
          " WHERE $prioridadeColumn = Media");
```

para

```
List listMap = await dbTarefas.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tarefasTable"    +
          " WHERE $prioridadeColumn = Media");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela tentativa, mas isso é do android studio o erro não é esse, mas obrigado

Comment: No dart voce pode quebrar as linhas de strings sem precisar usar o +